# Fill formula until the last row automatically

Tags: excel, vba

```
IF(ISBLANK(B5),"",IF(ISBLANK(O5)=TRUE,"Missing PSD",TODAY()-O5))
```

This is my formula that calculates the difference between the date in column O and current date. My first filled row with values is 5. The row in which the formula calculation is being done is AC.
I want to automatically calculate this until the last filled row and the row values should also increment like it does while dragging down.

I am not good with VBA so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `last filled row` to be calculated according to which column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testFilFormulaDown()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
 lastRow = sh.Range("O" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'chosen O:O column, being involved in the formula...
 sh.Range("AC5:AC" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(B5),"""",IF(ISBLANK(O5)=TRUE,""Missing PSD"",TODAY()-O5))"
End Sub
```

In order to properly calculate the last row, you must choose a fully filled column (A:A, C:C etc.). I used one involved in the formula, but since there is a check for blank cells, column O:O could not be the most appropriate one...

Comment: Got my desired result. Thank you so much!

Comment: Rohini Baburaj: Glad I could help!

Comment: How do I embed this in a module that I have? I tried this as an individual module and I could get the output. But when I add the sub to another module, I am getting neither the result nor an error.

Comment: @Rohini Baburaj: If I cannot see the "module that you have" I cannot help, I am afraid... Please, try editing your question and place there the `Sub` where you need to use the above solution. Theoretically, the code should be used exactly like you see it in the above code. Try inserting `Debug.Print lastRow` after it is defined and see what value it has. You maybe chosen a wrong column to determine the last row. Maybe...

Comment: Yes, it was a minor mistake from my side. It has been solved now. Works perfectly!